# Use Zend_Form Zend_Form_Element_File for Zend_Mail attachment's

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend_Form , Zend_Form_Element_File for adding an attachment to an email form .
My file Form element is Like this:

> ```
>     $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
>     $file->setLabel('File')
>              ->setRequired(true)
>               ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
> ```

and my send form Controller attachment part is :

```
            $at = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($value['file']));
            $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
            $at->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $at->filename    = $value['file']; // get this from posted form
            $mail->send();
```

My Problem is : The form send a file name to controller witch is useless and email send with empty file attached to it.

My Question is : How can i send full file content to Controller by Zend_Form ? or the file should be upload before sending ?

Answer (score 2):

Get the file from `tmp` folder. Try adding the following:

```
$fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ftempname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

And change the following lines to:

```
$at = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($ftempname));
$at->filename    = $fname;
```

Comment: I think you don't get it . file is in the user hard drive :)

Comment: This totally saved me! Thanks.